# Excel sum all values that match three criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum values in one column that match a month found in another column and a substring found in another column.

Sample Data:

```
DATE        DESCRIPTION                 ACCOUNT       AMOUNT
1/1/2018    Deposit - Account 1023345   Income    $ 1,000.00 
1/2/2018    Payment - Vendor 00359      Expenses  $  (435.12)
1/3/2018    Payment - Employee 0135     Salary    $(1,293.16)
```

Sample formula to get all payments made to vendor 00359 in January:

```
=SUMIFS(Daily!D2:Daily!D16384,
        Daily!A2:Daily!A16384,
        MONTH(Daily!A2:Daily!A16384)=1,
        Daily!C2:Daily!C16384,
        "Salary",
        Daily!B2:Daily!B16384,
        SEARCH("Vendor 00359", Daily!B2:Daily!B16384)
       )
```

This returns a value of "0" but it should be -435.12

**EDIT:** As Scott Craner mentioned, I need to create a new column for Month, which is easy enough, but I need to search for more than one item. How can I avoid creating a new column for each search criteria I need? I can foresee dozens of such searches that will need to take place.

Comment: You can't do `MONTH(Daily!A2:Daily!A16384)=1` as the criteria in SUMIFS().  You can create a new column that has that value then reference that column.

Comment: same with `Search`

Comment: So I need to create a month column (I can use the MONTH() function to do this) and then reference that column in the formula?

Comment: Correct, Same with Search.

Comment: Edited the original question with a problem regarding the search function. I can't create a new column for each search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Daily!D2:D16384,(1 = MONTH(Daily!A2:A16384))*(Daily!C2:C16384="Salary")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Vendor 00359",Daily!B2:B16384))))
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for pointing me to this function that I didn't know existed!